# Shadow Rendering in Collection View

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I created an extension of `UIButton` so that I could easily apply shadows to all of my buttons. I was trying to go for the elevation that is default in Android, and while it works on the first view, for some reason it's rendering improperly in the second.

```
func applyShadow() {

    layer.shadowColor = Color.shadow.cgColor

    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)

    layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0

    layer.shadowRadius = 10.0

    layer.masksToBounds = false

}
```

[image: Screenshots]

The one on the left is the intended appearance and it's nothing more than a simple stack view. The one on the right is the issue, and it is a collection view containing cells with buttons that are fully constrained to their parent cells. I'm calling the same apply shadow function so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried changing `layer.shadowOpacity` to something less than 1.0? Try `layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5` and go from there.